# Enable Internet access on the go in Ireland

Tags: cellphones, internet, ireland, data-plans

I have an unlocked Sony Xperia ZR which I want to use while travelling in Ireland. My objective is to stay connected to the Internet. Primary reason is to access maps and occasionally use other online applications, for which I think 3 to 5 GB will be fine (for around one month). Being able to make a few calls would be great.

I am using Vodafone and instead of using their roaming packages, I am planning to get a local (micro)SIM card. I have seen the Tesco mobile plans and their data plans for 5GB seems to be good, but it does not allow calling. Plans which allow calling does not have that much data bandwidth. Any suggestions on this or any other options is appreciated.

Comment: See this wiki http://prepaidwithdata.wikia.com/wiki/Ireland

Comment: The Sony Xperia ZR comes in two models, C5502 and C5503. Which do you have?

Comment: my experience is that mobile internet coverage on meteor is unbeaten in Ireland - and if i remember correctly they do have useful data/voice combined prepaid offers.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: My one is C5502

Comment: Can't you just get a data SIM locally and just switch to the home SIM for those few calls? If it's really just a few that might be actually be the cheaper solution. Perhaps drag along an old phone just for the calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tesco's broadband only SIMs are for tablets.

If you get a pay-as-you-go mobile phone SIM and top-up by €15 a month you get:

- unlimited calls to RoI mobiles and landlines,
- free texts to other Tesco Ireland mobiles,
- 250 webtexts (which can be sent from their mobile app),
- 5GB of data (an add-on which costs €10 a month)

and have €5 left for texts to other phones and international numbers. Their international rates aren't bad either.

Source: http://www.tescomobile.ie/priceplans/pay-as-you-go-plans.aspx

**NB**: If you're planning to spend any time in Northern Ireland you'll need to look at another option as roaming, particularly data roaming, is very expensive, and everything will be charged from your €5 residual credit.

Answer (score 3):

Doing extensive research before leaving the United States, I decided to purchase 2 "all you can eat" 30 day prepaid SIM cards for our iPhone 5s from Three (3) IE [3, all you can eat 4G Data Plan.](http://www.three.ie/eshop/phone-plans/prepay/). After 6 days usage in Dublin and Belfast I am very pleased. A nice overview is available at end of answer, thanks to Ken's Tech Tips. Take a look at all the different plans. Particularly recommended if you will be traveling around the EU is 3's "Feel at Home" package. More detail than you may want but all the plans as if March, 2015 here:[ken's tech tips, all you can eat/bring your own phone](http://kenstechtips.com/index.php/three-all-you-can-eat-data-reviewed#SIM_Only_Keep_Your_Current_Phone)